# HTTPS rewrites .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https

I have just had an SSL certificate installed to my site.
It was installed to the subdomain.

I have a rewrite on the sub domain so http://orderonline.mydomain.com.au uses web servers from the same server but in another account. This rewrite work fine.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^orderonline/?$  http://111.67.13.129/~dsoft/themes/RIV00/
```

However I can't seem it work with the https. The https is directed to the subfolder 'orderoline'.
How do I do a rewrite for the https to point to http://111.67.13.129/~dsoft/themes/RIV00/ but still maintain https//orderonline.mydomain.com.au.

Thanks in advance

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out.
I needed to change

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
```

However is it possible to do both?

d